# How to compute orbital decay of a cubesat?

Tags: reentry, cubesat, atmospheric-drag, drag, orbital-decay

I'd like to compute the orbital decay of a cubesat in LEO/VLEO due to atmospheric drag. Here is what I've done:

Based on the **Satellite Orbital Decay Calculations** document coming from the Australian government I managed to code a python script which computes the orbital decay of a satellite. The python script gives me the **exact same results** as in the paper.

However, when I compare it with the **Cubesat drag calculation** study and do their sanity check, it does not work.

First I noticed that if I put the effective area Ae in the script **I almost get the double of what I should**. I think it's linked to the Cd coefficient that is set at 2 in the paper. But the script asks for the area which is Ae/cd which double once more the result. I can't find why and that's really annoying.

Then, running the script with 2*Ae as A, it gives me  3.32 years before applying correction coefficient and 4.28 after, instead of 3.16 and 4.04.
It might sounds very close but it represents a 87,6 days difference which is a lot.
the only value I changed is the 0.33333 from the original script to 1/3.
So my 2nd question **is can anyone help me understand where does this difference come from?**

The last question is a**m I doing it right ? Can I get accurate results for 3U cubesat using the atmospheric model presented in those papers?**

Here are the references
https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1124870/
https://www.sws.bom.gov.au/Category/Educational/Space%20Weather/Space%20Weather%20Effects/SatelliteOrbitalDecayCalculations.pdf

here is my python code:

```
from math import*

M=0 #masse(kg)
A=0 #area?
H=0 #hauteur initiale (Km)
SRF=0 #solarradio flux en SFU (solar flux unit
GAI=0 #geomagneticAindex
Re=6378*1000 #earth radius in m
Me=5.98*10**24 #earth mass(kg)
G=6.67*10**(-11)
T=0 
dT=0.1 #time increment in days
D9=dT*3600*24 #to convert result in seconds
H1=10 #hauteur
H2=H #pour incrementation hauteur
k=0


DN=0
SH=0
k=0





# on rentre les valeurs
print('define the mass of the sat(kg)')
M=float(input())
print('define the area (mˆ2) of the sat 
A=float(input())
print('define initial height (km) of the sat')
H=float(input())
print('define solar radio flux  (conditions normales: F10.7 =80 \n ==> F10.7 va de 70-->200 (max et min case))')
SRF=float(input())
print('define géomagnetic A index (conditions normales: Ap=10')
GAI=float(input())
print("choose orbit inclination between 0-90  ")
i=float(input())
correction=1
if H<=325:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.35
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.62
if 325<H<=375:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.32
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.56        
if 375<H<=425:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.29
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.49
if 425<H<=475:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.26
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.43
if 475<H<=525:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.22
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.38
if 525<H<=575:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.19
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.31
if 575<H<=625:
    if 22.5<i<67.5:
        correction =1.17
    if 67.5<=i<=90:
        correction =1.25
if H>625:
    print(' correction coefficient is 1' )

    

R=Re+H*1000 #orbital radius in m
P=2*pi*sqrt(R**3/Me/G) #orbital period in s





#values recap
print('résumé infos:\n masse : ', M, ' kg \n surface: ',A, ' mˆ2 \n auteur initiale:', H, ' km \n solarradioflux: '
      , SRF, '\n geomagnetic A index: ', GAI)
print('\n période sat:',P)
print('\n rayon:',R)
matrice=[]


#keeping data
matrice2=['temps','hauteur','periode','mean motion','decay' ]



while H>180:
    SH=(900+2.5*(SRF-70)+1.5*GAI)/(27-0.012*(H-200))
    DN=6*10**(-10)*exp(-(H-175)/SH) #atm density
    dP=3*pi*A/M*R*DN*D9

    Pm=P/60
    MM=1440/Pm
    nMM=1440/((P-dP))/60
    Decay=dP/dT/P*MM

    H2=H2-H1

    P=P-dP

    T=T+dT
    R=(G*Me*P*P/4/pi/pi)**(1/3)
    H=(R-Re)/1000
    nvline=[T,H,P,MM,Decay]
    matrice.append(nvline)
    k+=1


print(matrice2[0],'\t\t\t',matrice2[1],'\t\t',matrice2[2],'\t\t',matrice2[3],'\t\t',matrice2[4])

    
for line in matrice:
    for el in line:
        print(el,end="\t")
    print()

print('\n' )
print(matrice2[0],'(jour)\t\t',matrice2[1],'(km)\t\t',matrice2[2],'(s)\t\t',matrice2[3],'(rev/jour)\t\t',matrice2[4],'(rev/jourˆ2)' )
print('\n' )
print('\n' )
print('\n' )
print('before correction: reentry after ', T, 'day or:', T/365,' years' )
T=T*correction    
print('apres correction: reentry after ', T, 'days or:', T/365,' years' )
```